# TCP Localhost Proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

Not sure what I'm looking for name-wise.. I want to setup a proxy on my server machine to monitor incoming packets and then reply to the client.

```
REMOTE     |   LOCAL   |   LOCAL      
Client_*  -->  Proxy  -->  Game Server
Client_A  <--  Proxy  <--  Game Server
Client_C  <--  Proxy  <--  Game Server
```

Below was close to what I want, however I need something meant for a server machine not client machine.
https://www.unknowncheats.me/forum/c-/74144-creating-packet-editor-proxy.html

Are there any certain libraries I should be looking at to achieve this? What should I be searching for?